# ASP.NET vs Java EE vs PHP

Tags: java, asp.net

In PHP we have to secure our website because by default, there is include faults, sql fails, etc. We MUST secure them
My question: Is it necessary to do it manually in Java EE or it is automatically managed by the technology ? And in Asp.NET ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to do it manually. Large amount of projects in JEE are based on Spring, so for security is commonly used Spring Security. You can also use "pure" JEE, details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbwy.html